# Как скачать файл по кускам?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, wget

Есть онлайн радио. На текущий момент я юзаю streamripper со следующими командами.

```
streamripper http://xxx.ru -M 100 -a audio
```

Скрипт качает аудио размером по 100МБ и сам новые файлы именует по индексу, т.е. audio1.mp3, audio2.mp3 и т.д.

Большинство файлов он начал сваливать в папку **incomplete**, поэтому хотел для теста сравнить скрипт на `bash`. Подскажите как с помощью либо `curl`, либо `wget` сделать тоже самое? Т.е. берем поток, качаем его пока размер файла не будет 100МБ и сохраняем его в файл с индексом. И так дальше

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21323442/4827341

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно воспользоваться опцией `-r` (`--range`) программы *curl*.

скачать первые сто мегабайт по `адресу`:

```
$ curl -r 0-104857599 адрес
```

следующие сто мегабайт:

```
$ curl -r 104857600-209715199 адрес
```

и т.д.

---

значения указывать надо в байтах. вычисления проще поручить оболочке:

```
$ curl -r 0-$((100*1024*1024-1)) адрес
$ curl -r $((100*1024*1024))-$((200*1024*1024-1)) адрес
```

---

> И так дальше

а дальше для автоматизации нужен цикл:

```
#!/bin/bash
u=$1
[ -n "$u" ] || { echo "использование: $0 адрес"; exit 1; }
n=0
p="часть"
s=100*1024*1024
while true; do
  printf -v f "%s%0.3d" $p $n
  echo -n "скачиваем $f"
  if ! curl -s -f -r $((n*s))-$(((n+1)*s-1)) "$u" > "$f"; then exit $?; fi
  echo ". готово. следующий номер: $((++n))"
done
```

Comment: а как сделать бесконечный цикл?

Comment: Чтобы в цикле скачивал audio1 потом audio2  и т.д

Comment: *а как сделать бесконечный цикл?* — мы же на сайте программистов находимся, или где? `while true; do ...; done`

Comment: Проблема в индексе. Как сделать нумерованные файлы

Comment: @Radzhab, в ответе файлы нумеруются.

Comment: Illegal number: 100*1024*1024
В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: @Radzhab, скрипт не меняли? как его запускаете? какая именно программа пишет это сообщение?

Comment: @Radzhab, проверил, скачивая файл. описанной вами ошибки не встретил. но есть «логическая» ошибка — *curl* не возвращает ошибку после «выхода за пределы файла», и скрипт, соответственно, продолжает работать бесконечно. это исправимо добавлением опции `-f` при вызове программы *curl*. я внёс изменения в ответ.