# Ошибка Illegal number в bash

Tags: linux, bash

Есть [скрипт для скачивания файла с удаленного сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607520/178576). При запуске пишет  `Illegal number: 100*1024*1024`. В чем может быть проблема?

```
#!/bin/bash
u=$1
[ -n "$u" ] || { echo "использование: $0 адрес"; exit 1; }
n=0
p="часть"
s=100*1024*1024
while true; do
  printf -v f "%s%0.3d" $p $n
  echo -n "скачиваем $f"
  if ! curl -s -f -r $((n*s))-$(((n+1)*s-1)) "$u" > "$f"; then exit $?; fi
  echo ". готово. следующий номер: $((++n))"
done
```

Comment: А у вас точно bash? Похоже на ошибку `dash`: `dash -c 's=1+1; echo $((s))'` выводит `dash: 1: Illegal number: 1+1`

Comment: Если интересна непосредственно причина, то проблема в том, как bash вычисляет арифметические выражения. Либо погуглите на эту тему, либо посмотрите в свое условие с curl`ом - там один из возможных вариантов вычисления.

P.S @AlexeyTen, "#!/bin/bash"

Comment: @AlexeyTen у меня стоит и Bash и Dash. запуск делаю через sh 1.sh url

Comment: @Radzhab ну так по умолчанию `sh` это `dash`. Запускайте `bash 1.sh ...`, а лучше сделайте скрипт исполняемым и запускайте `./1.sh ...`

Comment: НЕ используйте башизмы. Жизнь будет с одной стороны тяжелее (ну, язык сложный потому что), но с другой проще в переносимости.  `$((100*1024*1024))` чем не устроил?

Comment: @0andriy, 1. [арифметика присутствует в posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04). 2. почему dash не устраивает подстановка части арифметического выражения из переменной, мне разбираться не интересно. 3. единственная конструкция, которую (в вашей терминологии) можно назвать «башизмом» — это использование опции `-v` у внутренней команды `printf`.

Comment: @0andriy  4. с моей точки зрения «башизмом», «зэт-шизмом», «кей-шизмом» и тому подобными уничижительными терминами имеет хоть какой-то смысл (хотя и не стоит) называть случаи, когда в шебанге либо не указыается явно используемый интерпретатор вообще, либо вместо него указывается `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, 1. Да. 2. Я не понял о чём вы тут, как по вами же данной ссылке написано всё работает и в dash, о чём я указал ранее. 3. Также нужно избавляться. 4. Без разницы, пользователю никто не запрещает запустить `sh -x my-script`, что, например, я часто делаю, и вижу как некоторые творения вылетают. 5. И не перестану повторять: *shell — (очень) трудный ЯП*.

Comment: @0andriy, 2. об ошибке, которой посвящён данный вопрос. 3. это абсолютно равносильно утверждению «надо избавляться от „питонизмов“, потому что `sh файл-со-скриптом-на-питоне` работает некорректно». // правильная (в моём понимании здравого смысла) позиция — «надо использовать именно тот интерпретатор, для которого написан данный скрипт».

Comment: Переносимость у python гораздо выше, чем у shell. Писать на shell подразумевает писать переносимо, а это очень трудно. Мало кто это осознаёт к сожалению.

Comment: @0andriy, команда `sh файл-со-скриптом-на-питоне`, с моей точки зрения, лишена каких-либо признаков здравого смысла. если вы этого не понимаете, вся наша беседа прошла впустую. но даже если понимаете, я дальнейшую дискуссию продолжать не намерен.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, Вы мне про Фому...  Причём тут python вообще к теме shell?! Давайте обсуждать тогда правильнее ли запускать python 2.4 или python 2.7 для скрипта, который написан под python 2.7.

Comment: @0andriy, окей, мой последний комментарий. понятие shell («оболочка») не имеет никакого отношения ни к вопросу, ни к нашей дискуссии. если вы не понимаете даже столь базовых вещей, как «что такое программа и что такое оболочка, и почему программа может выполнять функции оболочки, но не наоборот», я вам **ничем** помочь не смогу. удачи вам и всего хорошего!

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, И это ещё не учитывая то, что вышеприведенный скрипт раза в три короче можно сделать (`man split`), не нагружая при этом сервер.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, в данном топике речь про *язык программирования*. Причём тут оболочка? Поставьте **ipython** в качестве $SHELL, обсудим.

Comment: Добавлю для знатоков всего и вся: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

скрипт написан для интерпретации именно программой *bash*.

вы можете использовать *bash* явно:

```
$ bash файл_со_скриптом ссылка
```

либо, добавив файлу бит исполнимости (`$ chmod u+x файл_со_скриптом`), неявно (путь к файлу интерпретатора будет взят из первой строки скрипта, оформленной как [*shebang*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_%28Unix%29)):

```
$ ./файл_со_скриптом ссылка
```

---

получаемое вами сообщение об ошибке свидетельствует о том, что для интерпретации была вызвана, скорее всего, программа *dash*. либо явно:

```
$ dash файл_со_скриптом ссылка
файл_со_скриптом: 8: printf: Illegal option -v
скачиваем файл_со_скриптом: 10: файл_со_скриптом: Illegal number: 100*1024*1024
```

либо неявно (если у вас `/bin/sh` является ссылкой на `/bin/dash`):

```
$ sh файл_со_скриптом ссылка
файл_со_скриптом: 8: printf: Illegal option -v
скачиваем файл_со_скриптом: 10: файл_со_скриптом: Illegal number: 100*1024*1024
```

Comment: Не стоит вдохновлять использовать людей башизмы, потом только хуже бывает :(